# WordPress conditional custom field

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to output a custom field in my single page of my WordPress install.
Basically, I want to output the related creative common license type in the page. So basically the custom field with key `cc-license` may have one value only, but the value must be one of the six creative common licenses.

Assuming I already insert the value for the key cc-license. So here is my code:

```
<?php 
$nilai = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cc-license', true);
echo $nilai; //just want to check the output,its ok!
if ($nilai = 'Attribution Non-commercial Share Alike') { ?>
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>                    
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is, if I change the value to any text, it still implement the HTML code in the conditional statement. Which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you might have just missed a =

```
<?php 
    $nilai = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cc-license', true);

    echo $nilai; //just want to check the output,its ok!

    if ($nilai == 'Attribution Non-commercial Share Alike') : ?>

        <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />
        This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>  

    <?php endif;
?>
```